# Remove comments validation (remove filter?)

Tags: filters, comments, validation

How i can remove wordpress comments content validation, I do not want to or examined the earlier there was no such comments.

I see for:

http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_filter_comment
http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/remove_filter
But i don't know how to do this.

[image: screenshot]

Question is: **how to remove comment validation on wordpress?**

Comment: What exactly do you want to achieve with this?

Comment: @Roberthue i want only remove comment validation -> http://i.imgur.com/lCzanth.png
i created ajax comments adding and i want remove default comments filter.

Answer (score 1):

If you take a look in source the condition for this message is `get_option('require_name_email')`. You can control it in *Settings* > *Discussion* > *Comment author must fill out name and e-mail*.

The programmatic way could be `add_filter( 'pre_option_require_name_email', '__return_null' );`

Comment: ok, but most important for me is remove checking if comment are added before.

because WordPress does not allow to add two comments with the same content in a row.

Comment: Please elaborate _in your question_ about _all_ cases you want to handle. Can't guess them from a single "validation" word. :)